# Register a custom twig extension with injected service in Symfony 3 causes an error

Tags: php, twig, symfony, twig-extension

I am using Symfony 3.1.3 and I have a service called "@app.actionmanager" who want to inject itself into a Twig extension to display the available actions (which is what "@app.actionmanager" is responsible). The fact is that every time I run:

```
$> php bin/console cache:clear
```

I receive the following error:

> [LogicException] Unable to register extension
>   "actionmanager_twig_extension" as extensions have already been
>   initialized.

The declaration of extension is:

```
app.twig.actionmanager:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\ActionManagerExtension
    arguments: ["@app.actionmanager"]
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

If I remove the injection of the service there is no problem. If I change the injection of such a service for another (eg @service_container) I keep getting the same error.

It seems that injecting a service in twig extension stop registering it into twig until the rest services has registered.

I searched the internet and no one else has this problem so I guess I must be doing something wrong just I do not know which.

Can you help?

P.S. Sorry for my bad english, it's not my mother language.

---

Edit: showing app.actionmanager declaration:

```
app.actionmanager:
   class: AppBundle\Services\ActionManager
```

---

Update: Cerad was right. @app.actionmanager is used by a compiler pass. Compiler Pass is causing this issue. I remove it and everything work.

I need compiler pass to build app.actionmanager so for now my workaround is to remove the twig extension and access app.actionmanager directly regitering it as a global variable in twig.

¿Is there any other way to do this?

Compiler pass file:

```
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class ActionContainerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // always first check if the primary service is defined
        if (!$container->has('app.actionmanager')) {
            return;
        }

        $manager = $container->findDefinition('app.actionmanager');

        // find all service IDs with the app.actioncontainer tag
        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('app.actioncontainer');

        foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $tags) {
            // add the service
            $manager->addMethodCall('addActions', array(new Reference($id)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of **@app.actionmanager** ?

Comment: Have you tried removing `public: false`?

Comment: Yes. I tried removing public: false and still don't working

Comment: You are using the standard method for loading services?  No compiler passes or stuff like that?  Really seems like what you posted should work.

Comment: I'm using a compiler pass and when I remove it everything work. I update my question with that info and code for the compiler.

is anyway of keep the service been used by compiler and make twig extension work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your Compiler Pass is called after the [Twig Extension Compiler Pass](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/TwigEnvironmentPass.php).

At this time Symfony use [this mecanism](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#controlling-the-pass-ordering) to order Compiler Pass.

And the twig compiler pass is defined [like this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TwigBundle.php#L33) (with the default **PassConfig::TYPE_BEFORE_OPTIMIZATION** = at first).

So you can't change the order at this time.

---

But in Symfony **3.2** (november 2016 release) you will be able to set a priority to a compiler pass, it was added [as new feature](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/18022) :

Comment: At least now i know whats wrong. I'll wait until november.

Thanks Alsatian.

Comment: If you don't want to go in prod you can already try 3.2@dev ;)